# display the 16 bits for the integer

Tags: c#, complement

i need your help , here is a part of my code but there is a problem that  i cant solve .
 Plese help me; 
This is what i have done for now , i can get positive integer in 16 bits binary form
`

```
        Console.WriteLine("Enter an integer : ");

        string inputnumber = Console.ReadLine();

        int num = int.Parse(inputnumber);

        string value = Convert.ToString(num, 2).PadLeft(16, '0');

        Console.WriteLine("The bits are : {0}", value);
        Console.ReadKey();`
```

AND the issue is how will i get negative value of an integer in 16 bits  binary form

like; when i input 5 , i can get  : 0000000000000101

```
   and i need -5 -------------> 1111111111111011
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C# `int` is a 32-bit type. You should use `short` (a 16-bit type) instead. For positive numbers up to 32767 the first (lower) 16 bits of `int` and `short` are the same, but for negative numbers it's different.

```
short num = short.Parse(inputnumber);
```

Comment: THANK YOU SOO MUCH , YOU SAVED MY LIFE :D :D

Comment: First 16 bits are not different, they are the same. -5 in 32bit is 11111111111111111111111111111011, lower 16 bits are equal.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek In a positional notation first digit is the least significant digit, so "first bits" and "lower bits" means the same. I edited my answer though to avoid any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

This is a correct behavior since it is stored in that way in a computer. That is the so called [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) where the most significant bit (the most left) tells you that this is a negative number. Also keep in mind that int contains 32 bits